# remove bootstrap .btn-group on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using below HTML tags to generate list of buttons and using `.btn-group` to group the buttons together.

```
<div class="btn-group mt-30">
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        exmaple 1
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        example 2
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        example 3
    </a>
</div>
```

which generates the view like
[image]

But on viewing the page on small device like mobile, the view is rendered as
[image]

On small devices, I want to remove `.btn-group` class because on small devices, I want to render each button in a new line like

[image]

Removing `.btn-group` from `div` renders view as shown in 3rd image.

**How can I apply `.btn-group` on large devices only, i.e., with `md` or `lg` and diable it on `sm`, `xs`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should overwrite `.btn-group .btn` on small devices:

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .btn-group .btn.btn-circle {
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Justinas' answer is probably better for this case, but if you wanted to actually have different markup for the different sized displays, you could use Bootstrap's [Responsive Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities).

```
<div class="btn-group mt-30 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        exmaple 1
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        example 2
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        example 3
    </a>
</div>
```

And on small devices:

```
<div class="visible-sm-block visible-xs-block">
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        exmaple 1
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        example 2
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-border-d btn-circle" href="#">
        example 3
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: this way I would have to write the same block for code twice, which I don't think is the best way.